# finding correct input tag to upload a image on instagram

Tags: python, html, selenium, instagram, web-deployment

i am trying to upload a image to instagram using Python and Selenium...
I need to emulate a phone and pass the image in a input tag, it works, because I can upload a profile picture, but the only problem is, that I cant find the correct input tag for uploading a image to my feed.
The only one i found was the one for uploading a new profile picture.

Could you please help me to find the input tag?

Here is the code im using:

```
  def upload(self, image, text):
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        #find input field
        upload_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "needed xpath")
        time.sleep(2)
        #send image
        upload_btn.send_keys("C:\\Users\\brend\PycharmProjects\ClimateCoinBot\\PP2.jpg") #full path of the file which is to be uploaded
```

Would be cool, if you could help me :)

Comment: Here is the full code, if it helps:
https://pastebin.com/nNdXEXMe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element to upload file with `.send_keys()` method can normally be located with the following locator:

```
upload_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
```

You should add a wait / delay after

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
```

before

```
upload_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "needed xpath")
```

to make the page fully loaded before accessing this element.
So your code can be something like this:

```py
def upload(self, image, text):
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
    time.sleep(2)
    #find input field
    upload_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
    #send image        
    upload_btn.send_keys("C:\\Users\\brend\PycharmProjects\ClimateCoinBot\\PP2.jpg")
```

But it is recommended to use explicit wait rather than hardcoded pauses.

Comment: Thanks :)
Are u sure, that the xpath is correct, because its still not uploading^^
https://pastebin.com/K7wbnw21

Comment: I'm not sure this element existing on the Instagram home page. Only web page actually having upload file button will have such element.

Comment: oh okay, i couldnt find the correct input tag since 4 days, but i know its there, because i can upload profile pictures like that.

Thank you for everything :)

Comment: In case my answer was helpful please upvote / accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm working in a instagram script with Selenium, and I'm in troubles like you. But I've found the code you're looking for. Take a look:

That's the story (send photo) code:

```
<button class="JdY43"> <span class="ctM9u _2dbep " role="link" tabindex="-1" style="width: 56px; height: 56px;">
<img alt="" class="_6q-tv" crossorigin="anonymous" data-testid="user-avatar" draggable="false" src="https://instagram.fgig4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/271673104_907632683286365_8637941351902776951_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fgig4-.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_cat=105&amp;_nc_ohc=nZGpq1e3_awAX_pI_zX&amp;edm=AIQHJ4wBAAAA&amp;ccb=7-4&amp;oh=00_AT-nr4lxSToGQqIQCitUKJQhDXaMCePqmSxEy77CzjlTjA&amp;oe=6212095C&amp;_nc_sid=7b02f1"></span>
<div class="XdXBI">Seu story</div> <div class="TiuNS">
<svg aria-label="Ícone de mais" class="_8-yf5 " color="#0095f6" fill="#0095f6" height="16" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16">
<path d="M12.001.504a11.5 11.5 0 1011.5 11.5 11.513 11.513 0 00-11.5-11.5zm5 12.5h-4v4a1 1 0 01-2 0v-4h-4a1 1 0 110-2h4v-4a1 1 0 112 0v4h4a1 1 0 010 2z">
</path></svg></div> 
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" role="presentation"><!-- look here -->
<input accept="image/jpeg" class="tb_sK" type="file"></form></button><!-- look here -->
```

Actually Instagram page have athe following structure:
Button Tag > (a lot of non important things) > form > input> (close button tag)

It's a smart way to hide the photo input. I waste too many hours searching for it.

So, you need to know: There is 4 input tags like as the listed above. You'll probably need to select them using a XPATH ilke:

> //*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/button/form/input

That, is the first problem. The second one is that input is with display attibute setted like "none!important". You can inject javaScript in console to fix it(I did and it and turned it in "inline").

But, I can't continue from this point, because when I send the file path to the input nothing happens.

So, if instead of just send the path, I use ".submit()" after send_keys I get the following message:

```
"This page could not be loaded. 
If cookies are active in your browser or it
is in Private, try enabling cookies or deactivate 
Private Mode and perform the action again."
```

That's everything that I have. I can upload photos using Selenium + Pyautogui, I've a script with it, and I use it when the time to click the button and set the path comes. But it's not usefull if you are in your own computer, it writes in other windows, if it's selected. We can talk about it, if you want. Although I'd this solution I really want a full selenium script.

I want to contribute to you research, so I would love if you answer if it worked for you, or contributed to you job, 'cause I want to keep building my bot. :)